# Changing form action using php

Tags: php, forms, action

`I have put together a form allowing people to register for an event online.  The form has some validation for the inputs and sends the $_POST values to an insert form and the insert form sends the data of a MYSQL database.  It works fine.

But I only want to send the data on if the email and confirm emails match.  If they match, the form sends the $_POST data to the insert form; if they don't match the form is represented to the user.

Stack overflow (Oct 27, 2012) suggested: `<form action =<?php echo $action; ?>`".

I can't get the following code to affect the form action:

```
<?php  
print_r($_POST);        
if($_POST['email'] !== $_POST['emailconf'])                 
{                   
    //echo "They are not equal"; 
    $action = "serraInsertForm.php";                
} 
else                
{   //echo "They are equal"; 
    $action = "serraRegFormComplete.php";           
}
 ?>
```

Notes:
    I want to do this with php.  Have not used javascript before.
    print_r show the $_POST value are OK
    The echo statements follow the logic of the if statements
    I tried to use different redirects in place of $action but that didn't work

I will appreciate any suggestions

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use JavaScript?  Doing this in PHP is possible but more effort than it is worth...

Comment: What you ask for is a simple validation process. I have made it myself, however I always have the insert process in the same page where the form is.

Comment: You typed the same paragraphs twice and the same code block twice, making it scary for the person who wanna solve the problem.

Comment: Might be a dumb question on my part, but are you actually setting the Location header after setting the action variable?  Header("Location: " . $action);

Comment: Why would you need to change the `action` attribute? Just include a different file in your php action script.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand why you want to do what you want to do... but I've updated my answer in the hopes that maybe it will help. Since you have said that you can see the valid $_POST values, then I have to assume that the rest of your code is working (the way you want/expect), and you simply want to call the code from either file based on if the values being = or !=.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Based on the update to your question. Maybe you could use this?

```
if ($_POST['email'] !== $_POST['emailconf'])                 
{                   
    //echo "They are not equal"; 
    include("serraInsertForm.php");
} 
else                
{
    //echo "They are equal"; 
    include("serraRegFormComplete.php");
}
```

This would allow you to keep the form in the "InsertForm" file, and the code for completion in the "FormComplete" file.

**Original:**

PHP is processed on the server side. So user input cannot change the form settings (without something like Javascript) on the client side. That being said since Javascript can be disabled (or modified in the console), I almost always write some sort of PHP check for the sever to validate as well.

My basic code for the form would be as such :

```
$bShowForm = true;

if (isset($_POST['email']))
{
    if ($_POST['email'] == $_POST['emailconf'])
    {
        $bShowForm = false;
        ... process form ...
        ... on process error, set error message and set bShowForm to true ...
        ... show thank you message ...
    }
    else
    {
        ... set error message ...
    }
}

if ($bShowForm)
{
    ... if error message, display ...
    ... form html ...
}
```